# SQL SELECT in another table with most recent date

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list of Matter data in **Table1** that I need to query, as well as get the **most recent** Invoice Number in **Table2** that is tied to the original Matter. I'm having extreme difficulty in joining these tables together and only getting one result for each Matter as I only want the most recent Invoice #.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

**Table1**

[image]

**Table2**

[image]

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Can you post sql that you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assigns numbers to each invoice row in order of date, and selects only the most recent.  Note that this assumes `InvoiceDate` is stored as a `date`,`datetime`, or something else that will sort chronologically, and that in the event of two invoices for the same date, returning either will be fine.  If you need to return both invoices in the event of ties, replace `row_number` with `rank`.

```
Select * from Table1 a
inner join 
    (Select *
    , row_number() over (partition by MatterID order by InvoiceDate desc) as RN
     from Table2) b
on a.MatterID = b.MatterID and b.RN = 1
```